# html2canvas img tag not taken to print

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

I am using html2canvas.js i am facing all chart image content is printing except the  tag not printing.

here is my code

```
<div id="printarea">
    <div id="layout1">
        <div>
            <div class="box">
            <div id="speedLineChart" class="chartElement"></div>
                <br/>
                <div id="zoombar123" style="clear:both;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <img style="width: 200px" src="http://www.igniteui.com/images/samples/dialog-window/content.jpg" />
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>

html2canvas(document.getElementById('printarea'), {

            onrendered: function(canvas) {
            WindowObject.document.body.appendChild(canvas);

            }
        });
```

in the speedLineChart div show the chart

Please any one help me.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please add the html as well,which you are trying to print?

Comment: Yes Here i edited 
in the speedLineChart div show the chart

Comment: CORS : by default html2canvas won't taint your canvas, but you can tell it to do so with the option `allowTaint: true` if its only for print and that you don't need to call `canvas.toDataURL` or `canvas.toBlob`.